# How to get current time for a specific time zone in postgres DB?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to get and compare current date time with multiple time zones in Postgres DB?

Answer (score 1):

By using this query we can get different time zone times instanlty.

```
select now(), now() at time zone 'utc', now() at time zone 'est',now() at time zone 'edt'
```

Comment: There are duplicate questions already. Besides, EST and EDT are ambiguous abbreviations. IST for example can be Irish, Israel or India Standard Time

Comment: Exactly. Better use time zone names by IANA, like 'America/New_York', 'Europe/Athens' or 'Asia/Kathmandu'.